# Java Spring response JSON String unescaped

Tags: java, json, spring, response, httpresponse

I have the following Spring Method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.GET ,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getProductById(

//ProductDTO database query in order to retrieve productg by ID and population

 final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productDTO);
 return new ResponseEntity<>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
```

That returns a product representation in JSON format,  the problem that I have is when I return this JSON , in the response I get it escaped like this:

```
"{\"uid\":\"test\",\"type\":\"Fragrance\",\"modifiedtime\":1575379505000,\"name\":\"test 
 name\",\"otherProperties\":{\"container\":false,\" ETC...``
```

I would need it unescaped in the response , how can I achieve this?

The reason I transform the DTO manually is because if I just return the DTO in the ResponseEntity the representation of the JSON handled by Spring is not the same as the one I get using objectMapper.writeValueAsString method , instead of getting this:

```
"name": "nombre de prueba",
  "otherProperties": {
    "container": false,
    "onlineExclusive": false,
    "sizeGuide": "size guide",etc..
```

I get this:

````
 "name": "nombre de prueba",
  "otherProperties": [
    {
      "key": "container",
      "value": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "value": false
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "onlineExclusive",
      "value": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "value": false
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "sizeGuide",
      "value": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "size guide"
      }
    },
    ```
````

Comment: Just return `ResponseEntity<ProductDto>` instead of wring a string yourself, Spring will handle the JSON conversion.

Comment: Don't add additonal information as comments, edit your question instead. You shouldn't be doing the JSON serializing yourself. Spring will handle that for you using the pre-configured `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've edited the question. Can you check it please?

Comment: Apparently `otherProperties` is a map, which gets serialized differerntly. Instead of working around Spring, work with the framework and configure the default `ObjectMapper` as you want.

Comment: otherProperties is a linked Hash Map , however  , why ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString is returning the JSON in the format I need while Spring isn't ? How can I change that ?

Comment: As mentioned by configuring it. You can configure the object mapper through propreties in the `application.properties` file. Or maybe you already, accidentally reconfigured it with the other JSON as a result.

Comment: Which property I should modify in order to achieve my purpose ?